# Android - Studio java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, excepciones

Tengo una actividad principal donde despliego un pop up desde un cardview, necesito que los datos de las rutas, como el nombre y la foto aparezcan dentro del layout de la ruta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que los datos aparezcan dentro de la segunda captura, pero me aparece este error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.recyclerviewexample, PID: 23058
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.recyclerviewexample.MainActivity.showPopUp(MainActivity.java:91)
    at com.example.recyclerviewexample.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:52)
    at com.example.recyclerviewexample.MyAdapter$ViewHolder$1.onClick(MyAdapter.java:70)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22298)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
```

Aquí está mi método showPopUp:

```
public void showPopUp(int position) {
    String nombre = lineas.get(position).getNombre();
    int foto = lineas.get(position).getId();

    //inicializar controles popup
    myDialogo.setContentView(R.layout.custom_popup);
    popup_imgvlinea = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.popup_imgvlinea);
    popup_txtnombrelinea = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.popup_txtnombrelinea);

    Toast.makeText(this, nombre, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    popup_txtnombrelinea.setText(nombre);
    popup_imgvlinea.setImageResource(foto);
    myDialogo.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    myDialogo.show();
}
```

Que este mismo es invocado desde aquí:

```
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(lineas, R.layout.recycler_view_item, new MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(Linea linea, int position) {
        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, linea.getDescripcion() + " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        showPopUp(position);
    }
});
```

Aquí está mi XML del pop up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_popup"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:gravity="clip_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/popup_imgvlinea"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/linea1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/popup_txtnombrelinea"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Linea 1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/popup_tvdescripcion"
            android:text="descripcion"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Entiendo que `popup_txtnombrelinea` es nul, es decir que no encuentra el objeto `popup_txtnombrelinea` dentro del layout (nombres de variables poco acertadas, duplicidad con el nombre del objeto y confusión). Revisa el layout y por qué no encuentra el objeto.

Comment: Parece que el layout `custom_popup` no tiene un TextView cuyo id sea `popup_txtnombrelinea` revisa ese layout y verifica.

Comment: Ya verifiqué todo, los ids si están dentro de mi custom_popup.xml.

Comment: al presionar un elemento deseas levantar un vista como un dialog?

Comment: Si, asi es. Quiero poner los datos de mi objeto dentro de ese layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instanciar mi Dialog dentro del metodo showPopUp:

```
public void showPopUp(int position){
    String nombre = lineas.get(position).getNombre();
    int foto = lineas.get(position).getId();

    myDialogo = new Dialog(this);
    myDialogo.setContentView(R.layout.custom_popup);
    popup_imgvlinea = (ImageView) myDialogo.findViewById(R.id.popup_imgvlinea);
    popup_txtnombrelinea = (TextView) myDialogo.findViewById(R.id.popup_txtnombrelinea);

    popup_txtnombrelinea.setText(nombre);
    popup_imgvlinea.setImageResource(foto);
    myDialogo.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    myDialogo.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El error esta en que estas tomando mal el textView, probrablemente lo esta buscando en tu activity y no en tu popup

El fix es el siguiente:

```
//Suponiendo que myDialogo es instanciado con un New en algun momento
myDialogo.setContentView(R.layout.custom_popup);
popup_imgvlinea = (ImageView) myDialogo.findViewById(R.id.popup_imgvlinea);
popup_txtnombrelinea = (TextView) myDialogo.findViewById(R.id.popup_txtnombrelinea);
```

Revisa que tambien estes instanciando el dialog

```
myDialogo = new Dialog(...);
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Gracias me diste la idea de instanciarlo dentro del metodo showPopup! :) me sirvió mucho

Comment: De nada! me alegro que hayas podido solucionarlo :D